# How does the 'binding' attribute work in JSF? When and how should it be used?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, binding, components

There are lot of materials out there differentiating `value` attribute and `binding` attribute in JSF.

I'm interested in how both approaches differ from each other. Given:

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private UICommand link;

    // Getters and setters omitted.
}
```

```xhtml
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink binding="#{user.link}" value="#{user.name}" />
</h:form>
```

It is pretty straight forward what happens when a `value` attribute is specified. The getter runs to return the `name` property value of the `User` bean. The value is printed to HTML output.

But I couldn't understand how `binding` works. How does the generated HTML maintain a binding with the `link` property of the `User` bean?

Below is the relevant part of the generated output after manual beautification and commenting (note that the id `j_id_jsp_1847466274_1` was auto-generated and that there are two hidden input widgets).
I'm using Sun's JSF RI, version 1.2.

```html
<form action="/TestJSF/main.jsf" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    id="j_id_jsp_1847466274_1" method="post"  name="j_id_jsp_1847466274_1">
    <input name="j_id_jsp_1847466274_1" type="hidden" value="j_id_jsp_1847466274_1">
    <a href="#" onclick="...">Name</a>
    <input autocomplete="off" id="javax.faces.ViewState" name="javax.faces.ViewState"
        type="hidden" value="-908991273579182886:-7278326187282654551">
</form>
```

Where is the `binding` stored here?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

### How does it work?

When a JSF view (Facelets/JSP file) get built/restored, a JSF component tree will be produced. At that moment, the [view build time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31890433/whats-the-view-build-time), all `binding` attributes are evaluated ([along with `id` attribtues and taghandlers like JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)). When the JSF component needs to be created before being added to the component tree, JSF will check if the `binding` attribute returns a precreated component (i.e. non-`null`) and if so, then use it. If it's not precreated, then JSF will autocreate the component "the usual way" and invoke the setter behind `binding` attribute with the autocreated component instance as argument.

In effects, it binds a reference of the component instance in the component tree to a scoped variable. This information is in no way visible in the generated HTML representation of the component itself. This information is in no means relevant to the generated HTML output anyway. When the form is submitted and the view is restored, the JSF component tree is just rebuilt from scratch and all `binding` attributes will just be re-evaluated like described in above paragraph. After the component tree is recreated, JSF will restore the JSF view state into the component tree.

### Component instances are request scoped!

Important to know and understand is that the concrete component instances are effectively request scoped. They're newly created on every request and their properties are filled with values from JSF view state during restore view phase. So, if you bind the component to a property of a backing bean, then the backing bean should **absolutely not** be in a broader scope than the request scope. See also [JSF 2.0 specitication](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jsf-2.0-fr-full-oth-JSpec/) chapter 3.1.5:

> #### 3.1.5 Component Bindings
>
> ...
>
> Component bindings are often used in conjunction with JavaBeans that are dynamically instantiated via the Managed
> Bean Creation facility (see Section 5.8.1 “VariableResolver and the Default VariableResolver”). **It is strongly
> recommend that application developers place managed beans that are pointed at by component binding expressions in
> “request” scope.** This is because placing it in session or application scope would require thread-safety, since
> UIComponent instances depends on running inside of a single thread. There are also potentially negative impacts on
> memory management when placing a component binding in “session” scope.

Otherwise, component instances are shared among multiple requests, possibly resulting in "[duplicate component ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101755/im-getting-duplicate-id-error-after-adding-binding-attribute)" errors and "weird" behaviors because validators, converters and listeners declared in the view are re-attached to the existing component instance from previous request(s). The symptoms are clear: they are executed multiple times, one time more with each request within the same scope as the component is been bound to.

And, under heavy load (i.e. when multiple different HTTP requests (threads) access and manipulate the very same component instance at the same time), you may face sooner or later an application crash with e.g. [Stuck thread at UIComponent.popComponentFromEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30093791/stuck-thread-at-uicomponent-popcomponentfromel), or [Threads stuck at 100% CPU utilization in HashMap during JSF saveState()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32879014/java-threads-at-100-cpu-utilization-using-richfaces-uidataadaptorbase-and-its-i), or even some "strange" `IndexOutOfBoundsException` or `ConcurrentModificationException` coming straight from JSF implementation source code while JSF is busy saving or restoring the view state (i.e. the stack trace indicates `saveState()` or `restoreState()` methods and like).

Also, as a single component basically references the rest of the entire component tree via `getParent()` and `getChildren()`, when binding a single component to a view or session scoped bean, you're essentially saving the entire JSF component tree in the HTTP session for nothing. This will get really costly in terms of available server memory when you have relatively a lot of components in the view.

Sure, this all could probably be solved by making JSF components thread safe by adding `synchronized` over all place, but still they are never intended to be shared across different browser tabs/windows/sessions because that would for the end user only end up in "wtf?" behavior, and moreover that would hugely knock down the performance.

### Using `binding` on a bean property is bad practice

Binding a whole component instance to a bean property, even on a request scoped bean, is in a properly designed JSF application a rather rare use case and generally not the best practice. It indicates a design smell. You normally declare components in the view side and bind their runtime attributes like `value`, and perhaps others like `styleClass`, `disabled`, `rendered`, etc, to normal bean properties. Then, you just manipulate exactly that bean property you want instead of grabbing the whole component and calling the setter method associated with the attribute.

In cases when a component needs to be "dynamically built" based on a static model, better is to use [view build time tags like JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596456/display-a-list-of-images-in-a-table-format-in-jsf/), if necessary in a [tag file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713718/how-to-make-a-grid-of-jsf-composite-component), instead of `createComponent()`, `new SomeComponent()`, `getChildren().add()` and what not. See also [How to refactor snippet of old JSP to some JSF equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732567/how-to-refactor-snippet-of-old-jsp-to-some-jsf-equivalent)

Or, if a component needs to be "dynamically rendered" based on a dynamic model, then just use an [iterator component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409053/jsf2-can-i-add-jsf-components-dynamically/) (`<ui:repeat>`, `<h:dataTable>`, etc). See also [How to dynamically add JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409053/how-to-dynamically-add-jsf-components).

Composite components is a completely different story. It's completely legit to bind components inside a `<cc:implementation>` to the backing component (i.e. the component identified by `<cc:interface componentType>`. See also a.o. [Split java.util.Date over two h:inputText fields representing hour and minute with f:convertDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235721/split-java-util-date-over-two-hinputtext-fields-representing-hour-and-minute-wi/) and [How to implement a dynamic list with a JSF 2.0 Composite Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358066/how-to-implement-a-dynamic-list-with-a-jsf-2-0-composite-component/)

### Only use `binding` in local scope

However, sometimes you'd like to know about the state of a different component from inside a particular component, more than often in use cases related to action/value dependent validation. For that, the `binding` attribute can be used, but *not* in combination with a bean property. You can just specify an in the local EL scope unique variable name in the `binding` attribute like so `binding="#{foo}"` and the component is during render response elsewhere in the same view directly as `UIComponent` reference available by `#{foo}`. Here are several related questions where such a solution is been used in the answer:

- [Validate input as required only if certain command button is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729982)
- [How to render a component only if another component is not rendered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715574)
- [JSF 2 dataTable row index without dataModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633008)
- [Primefaces dependent selectOneMenu and required="true"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14537567)
- [Validate a group of fields as required when at least one of them is filled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458829)
- [How to change css class for the inputfield and label when validation fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452594)
- [Getting JSF-defined component with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402601)
- [Use an EL expression to pass a component ID to a composite component in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271380)

  *(and that's only from the last month...)*

### But I need to fix an existing train wreck ASAP

If you have an existing JSF app where the `binding` is abusively referencing a bean in a scope larger than request, and you merely wanted to fix it in the shortest possible time as possible in order to fix severe memory and thread safety problems, then your best bet is to (regex) find&replace the getters and setters of the following form:

```java
public SomeComponent getSomeComponent() {
    return someComponent;
}
public void setSomeComponent(SomeComponent someComponent) {
    this.someComponent = someComponent;
}
```

to the following form:

```java
public SomeComponent getSomeComponent() {
    return getBoundComponent("someComponent");
}
public void setSomeComponent(SomeComponent someComponent) {
    setBoundComponent("someComponent", someComponent);
}
```

with the following helper methods which basically save them in the request scope:

```java
protected static <C extends UIComponent> C getBoundComponent(String key) {
    return (C) getBoundComponents().get(key);
}
protected static <C extends UIComponent> void setBoundComponent(String key, C component) {
    getBoundComponents().put(key, component);
}
private static <C extends UIComponent> Map<String, C> getBoundComponents() {
    return (Map<String, C>) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap()
        .computeIfAbsent("com.example.BOUND_COMPONENTS", $ -> new HashMap<>());
}
```

and then let the IDE (auto-)remove unused fields.

#### See also:

- [How to use component binding in JSF right ? (request-scoped component in session scoped bean)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667927)
- [View scope: java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31485892)
- [Binding attribute causes duplicate component ID found in the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101755)

Comment: I set user as request scoped bean. And tried sysout in getlink and setlink methods. When landing on the page = `User.User(), User.getLink(), User.setLink(), User.getValue()`
When i click the link = `User.User(), User.setLink()...`

Comment: Why is setLink() called again and an another UICommand object created when it has one already?

Comment: "if you bind [...], then the backing bean should absolutely not be in a broader scope than the request scope". Is this still true in JSF 2.2? What's is the best option if I have to programatically include components in the page using getChildren().addAll(...)?

Comment: @Rinaldo: Use JSTL to programmatically build the view in just XML syntax.

Comment: What if XML syntax is not an option? :P

Comment: @BalusC: You mentioned in your answer that ..When the form is submitted and the view is restored,....(POSTBACK), the JSF component tree is just (REBUILT) from scratch. I am a little confused here. Since a view is a just a tree of UI components, and in this specific case was restored from the initial GET request, it must be also be providing that specific tree structure. Why the need to rebuilt it again for the POST request. Or is the component tree rebuilt on every single request? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Shirgill: "view state" is not the component tree itself, but its (changed) state. I.e. all properties/attribtues which are different from defaults. When the component tree is rebuilt, the (changed) state is restored. Maybe this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31890433/whats-the-view-build-time (also the 1st link in 1st paragraph of the above answer)

Comment: @BalusC: So, when they say the view state needs to be preserved(stateful) so as to process the lifecycle, it implies only saving the component state, but not the component tree.

Comment: @Shirgill: Indeed. `UIViewRoot` (all of `UIComponent` basically) is unserializable anyway.

Comment: @BalusC: Component instances are request scoped. Since, the bean will be garbage-collected after the request has been served, and so will that  component instance declared in the same bean. So, in which case will there be a precreated component?

Comment: @Shirgill: you're all responsible for it yourself. E.g. `component = new SomeComponent()` in post construct. If there isn't such one, JSF will take care of it.

Comment: @BalusC: Didn't get your point. You mean that component instance won't be garbage collected.

Comment: @Shirgill: it will be GC'ed. You're all responsible for precreating one, if necessary (usually not).

Comment: @BalusC: Got it. You second last comment after being edited was reflected when I had added a comment. Thank you very much.

Comment: @BalusC Is binding can be responsible of high memory consuming? We were using binding with `p:toolbarGroup` in a ViewScoped bean, and the retain heap of the bean was 15Mo! Wish I could attach an image to show you... Since, we replaced the use of toolbarGroup with another Primefaces component and no binding, it looks way much better now :) But I'm still wondering why so much memory consumed...

Comment: @Rapster: that can happen if bean is not request scoped, as explained in answer. You're basically referencing the entire JSF component tree.

Comment: Does it mean ViewScoped is much more memory consuming than RequestScoped? In theory, yes of course, but is it possible it could be that much (outside binding) ?

Comment: @Rapster: view scoped beans are stored in session. It's only memory consuming if you store unnecessary data along it. That's not JSF's fault.

Answer (score 1):

each JSF component renders itself out to HTML and has complete control over what HTML it produces. There are many tricks that can be used by JSF, and exactly which of those tricks will be used depends on the JSF implementation you are using.

- Ensure that every from input has a totaly unique name, so that when the form gets submitted back to to component tree that rendered it, it is easy to tell where each component can read its value form.
- The JSF component can generate javascript that submitts back to the serer, the generated javascript knows where each component is bound too, because it was generated by the component.
- For things like hlink you can include binding information in the url as query params or as part of the url itself or as matrx parameters. for examples.

  `http:..../somelink?componentId=123` would allow jsf to look in the component tree to see that link 123 was clicked. or it could e `htp:..../jsf;LinkId=123`

The easiest way to answer this question is to create a JSF page with only one link, then examine the html output it produces. That way you will know exactly how this happens using the version of JSF that you are using.

Comment: I would say that I've only used component binding when generating the component dynamically in server side, setting all the attributes like  `action` and `value`, and then let the JSF framework make his job.

Comment: I stored `user` as application scoped managed bean and when I click the link every time only the second number in `value="-908991273579182886:-7278326187282654551"` changes and every thing else is same. Wonder what magic these does.